Cant parse application.json conncetion string for ASP.NET Core Web API
Here is my function to create a datatable. cntNV is the connection string from application.json.
public static DataTable GetDataTableOracle(string SQL, string strParameter1, object objParameter1)
    {
        var cntNV = GetNvisonConnectionString();

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(cntNV))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (OracleCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.BindByName = true;
                cmd.CommandText = SQL;

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strParameter1))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(strParameter1, objParameter1);
                }

                using (OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    dt.Load(reader);
                }
            }
        }

        return dt;
    }

I'm trying to upgrade an old legacy API with a new ASP.NET Core Web API using VS 2022. Here is an example of the connection string that can't be parsed in the application.json file.
"ConnectionStrings":{
  "nVisionConnectionString":
    "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=xxxprd-ih.tic.com:2405/ORCL)(PORT=2405)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=XXXPRD)));User Id =TheUser;Password=ABCDEFG"
}

Is there a simple example of the correct connection string format for connecting to an Oracle Managed Data access app? I don't want to use a wallet or anything else.

https://www.connectionstrings.com ?

"can't be parsed in the application.json" ASP.NET Core expects to find configuration in appsettings.json

What database are you connecting to?

I'm retrieving the "string" without issue in my function from application.json

I'm connecting to an oracle db

Here is my function to create a datatable  the var cntNV is the string pulled from the application.json file and the string is being passed without issue.

Did you look at and try the alternatives offered by https://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle/ ? What is the exact error that you are getting, and on which line of code does it occur?

Exception thrown: 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException' in Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll
An exception of type 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException' occurred in Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll but was not handled in user code
Oracle Communication: Failed to connect to server or failed to parse connect string

Try to set the connection string like this:
"ConnectionStrings": {   "nVisionConnectionString": "User Id=TheUser;Password=ABCDEFG;Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=xxxprd-ih.tic.com)(PORT=2405)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=XXXPRD)))" }
and to use it in your code:
var connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("nVisionConnectionString");
